# how to convert a big unequally nested list into data.frame/datatable in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I made a very big list `twitter`. Each top sublist `twitter[[i]]` is made for each tweet.However not every top sublist has the same structure, some of them may not have some specific slot. How can I convert such list into a data frame whose's each row contain each tweet's information and use `NA` to make up the missing information.

Let's take `twitter[[10101]]`(edited) for example:

```
 > str(twitter[[10101]])
 $ retweeted                  : logi FALSE
 $ text                       : chr "RT @TeriChristoph: W-T-H??? 'Rep. Speier: \030Women Will Attain The Position of First Class Citizens\031 Under Obamacare' http:"| __truncated__
 $ id_str                     : chr "182608843031842816"
 $ source                     : chr "<a href=\"http://www.tweetdeck.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">TweetDeck</a>"
 $ entities                   :List of 3
  ..$ urls         :List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 4
  .. .. ..$ indices     : num [1:2] 116 136
  .. .. ..$ display_url : chr "shar.es/p4fyt"
  .. .. ..$ url         : chr "http://t.co/T62gHwaE"
  .. .. ..$ expanded_url: chr "http://shar.es/p4fyt"
  ..$ user_mentions:List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 5
  .. .. ..$ id_str     : chr "15932085"
  .. .. ..$ screen_name: chr "TeriChristoph"
  .. .. ..$ name       : chr "Teri Christoph"
  .. .. ..$ id         : num 15932085
  ..$ hashtags     : list()
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
 $ favorited                  : logi FALSE
 $ contributors               : NULL
 $ place                      : NULL
 $ created_at                 : chr "Wed Mar 21 23:25:15 +0000 2012
 $ geo                        : NULL
 $ user                       :List of 38
  ..$ is_translator                     : logi FALSE
  ..$ show_all_inline_media             : logi FALSE
  ..$ profile_link_color                : chr "9D582E"
  ..$ id_str                            : chr "16504112"
  ..$ name                              : chr "Sheryl"
 $ id                         : num 1.83e+17
 $ truncated                  : logi FALSE
```

Comment: There are many answers already given on converting lists with sublists to data frames. Did any of them help? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+list+to+data+frame

Comment: There is an `rbind.fill` function in pkg:plyr whose description is 
"Combine data.frames by row, filling in missing columns." If you had presented the data with `dput( twitter[10100:10102] )`, I would have attempted a solution.

Comment: You might also wanna try `data.table::rbindlist(... , fill=TRUE)`